# php remove "questionmarks" � from fail-encoded text

Tags: php, string, encode

i´m extracting some text from a weblink  with file_get_contents,  i have no influence on the text, the bits i talk about are already malformed in the sourcecode of the weblink i got the contents from  ,
and look sth. like so :

```
 /$%§&fdsgfkgfd � fdsfdsfs � � -->
 <h1>m�lll</h1>
 <h1>m�lll</h1>
 <h1>m�lll</h1>
 <h1>m�lll</h1>
 <h1>m�lll</h1>
 <h1>m�lll</h1>
```

or

```
 <<<!-- � födns
```

my php file is not meant to "be" an html file so its just a string  im dealing with,

I searched the internet but its difficult with that icon,

i want to remove them
because they are not necessary,
how can i remove them ?

ps: i´m not looking through a browser, i var_dump the text in a console

Solution:

i use tthis function for first cast the string as utf-8 string

```
function convToUtf8($str) 
{ 
if( mb_detect_encoding($str,"UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, GBK")!="UTF-8" ) 
{ 

return  iconv("gbk","utf-8",$str); 

} 
else 
{ 
return $str; 
} 

}
```

Comment: How are you grabbing this text?

Comment: file_get_contents, maybe thats the key ?

Comment: Is the text already utf-8 or are you just trying to display it as utf-8?

Comment: It would be better to try to detect the character encoding of the file instead of "fixing" UTF-8 encoding that may not have been intended in the first place.

Comment: Have you declared the charset in your HTML? <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: this is how i receive it and how it looks like when i dump it into a console

Comment: its not inside a html document its just a string im handling in a command with php

Comment: @MitchLayzell The declaration belongs in the HTTP `Content-Type` header field value in the first place, which would take precedence over `meta` elements.

Comment: and i have no influence on it, in the source code im getting it of its already with that �

Comment: @PointedEars if he never set the content-type header the meta utf-8 would be fine.

Comment: @MitchLayzell Yes, but too many assumptions on your part.

Comment: Use [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/mb_detect_encoding), and then [iconv()](http://php.net/iconv) to convert to UTF-8.

Comment: How are you getting the html ? `curl` ? `file_get_contents` ?

Comment: @PointedEars you should post an answer

Comment: @Musa I want to clarify the problem first.

Comment: im trying mb_detect and iconv

Comment: it worked, yüaäääh thanks i update my question, feel free to make an answer of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can discard characters that are not supported by an encoding, with [`iconv()`](http://php.net/iconv):

```
$converted = iconv($input_encoding, $output_encoding . '//IGNORE', $original);
```

There are two drawbacks:

1. You need to know the input encoding, and
2. as you can read in [a user comment in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#108643), `iconv()` has a bug so that `'//IGNORE'` does not work with recent versions of the iconv library.  The suggested workaround is (here for UTF-8):

   ```
   ini_set('mbstring.substitute_character', 'none'); 
   $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
   ```

However, it is much better to attempt to detect the input encoding and convert the input to the output encoding. This leads to:

```
function recode ($input, $output_encoding)
{
  $input_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($input);

  if ($input_encoding === false)
  {
    $old_substitute = mb_substitute_character();
    mb_substitute_character('none'); 

    $converted = mb_convert_encoding($input, $output_encoding, $output_encoding);

    mb_substitute_character($old_substitute);
  }
  else
  {
    $converted = ($output_encoding !== $input_encoding)
      ? iconv($input_encoding, $output_encoding, $input)
      : $input;
  }

  return $converted;
}
```